# Android Volley JsonArrayRequest

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

El PHP que a través de una SQL me entrega un listado de registros me devuelve lo siguiente

```
PHP
$result = $con->query($query);
for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = json_encode($row));
print_r($set);

RESULTADO
Array
(
[0] => {"id":"8783","nombre":"pepe","username":"demo"}
[1] => {"id":"8784","nombre":"garcia","username":"demo"}
)
```

Ahora como proceso eso desde Android con Volley, yo tengo lo siguiente pero obviamente no funciona

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_2,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String nombre = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                        Log.e("nombre", nombre);
                                        mEntries.add(jsonObject.toString());

                                    }
                                    catch(JSONException e) {
                                        mEntries.add("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
```

El error que arroja es

> ```
> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Array of Type 
> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
> ```

Les agradezco si pudieran verificar el Volley o bien modificar el PHP para que se adapte al Volley

Modifico el volley dejando solamente lo siguiente dentro del try y arroja el mismo error

```
try {
   Integer cantidad = jsonArray.length();
   Log.e("cantidad: ", cantidad.toString());
}
```

Comment: User, añade eso como edicion de la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Según dice la documentación del [código fuente](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/ParseError.java) de la clase `com.android.volley.ParseError`

> Indicates that the server's response could not be parsed.

El problema no está en el código de **Java** sino en el código **PHP** y la forma en que devuelves los resultados. El siguiente código funciona, supone que existe la tabla `users` con los campos `id, nombre, username`:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "yo", "test");

/* comprobar la conexion */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$set = array();

if ($result = $con->query($query)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $set[] = $row;
    }

    $result->close();
}
$con->close();

// Especificar que el contenido es del tipo application/json
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode($set);
```

Este código devuelve:

```
[{"id":"1","nombre":"Pepe","username":"user_pepe"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Roberto","username":"user_roberto"},{"id":"3","nombre":"Alberto","username":"user_alberto"}]
```

que es una respuesta valida de `JSON`.

Comment: Encantado de contribuir. Por favor, hazme saber si te ayudó.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pero ese código me devuelve vacío, lo estoy probando con Postman y no me devuelve nada. Aclaro que la consulta la probé en la base de datos y arroja 540 registros

Comment: He actualizado el código, lo probé y funciona. Pruébalo y si puedes me dices. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error te dice que estás enviando una cadena, cuando Android está esperando un `JSONArray`, que no es lo mismo que un `JSONObject`.

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) { ...
```

¿En qué se diferencia un `JSONArray` de un `JSONObject`?

En que el `JSONArray` sería algo así más o menos (empieza y termina por `[]`):

```
[{
    "0": {
        "id": "8783",
        "nombre": "pepe",
        "username": "demo"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "8784",
        "nombre": "garcia",
        "username": "demo"
    }
}]
```

**Esto es lo único que debería imprimir tu servicio PHP, nada más.**

---

Si Android esperase un `JSONObject` sería algo así más o menos (empieza y termina por `{}` y Android lo trata como una cadena, de hecho, para manipular un JSONObject debes convertirlo:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "8783",
        "nombre": "pepe",
        "username": "demo"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "8784",
        "nombre": "garcia",
        "username": "demo"
    }
}
```

Puesto que en el código tienes esto:

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {...
```

Tu respuesta **debe ser algo parecido a esto**:

```
[{
    "0": {
        "id": "8783",
        "nombre": "pepe",
        "username": "demo"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "8784",
        "nombre": "garcia",
        "username": "demo"
    }
}]
```

o cualquier otra forma de `JSONArray` válida.

Si esperas un `JSONArray` puedes crear tu JSON así:

```
$json=json_encode($set);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo "[".$json."]";
```

Si por el contrario, Android esperase un `JSONObject`...

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) { ...

$json=json_encode($set);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo $json;
```

Evidentemente, en este segundo caso, la forma de leer la respuesta (*parsear*), sería distinta.

**Nota:** la última línea es la única salida en pantalla que deberá tener tu servicio. Es decir, lo único que debes imprimir es lo que Android espera, y como Android lo espera, nada más.

En cuanto a esta línea: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');`,  si ya la tienes en otra parte del script, no es necesario ponerla aquí. Se usa para indicar que la respuesta tendrá un contenido del tipo `json` y que el encodaje será `utf-8`.

Comment: No resulto, si solamente en el PHP le pongo
`
$result = $con->query($query);
$set = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $set[] = $row;

}
print_r($set);
`
Me arroja
`
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8783
           ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8784
         ....
        )
`

Comment: A ver, todo eso del while es innecesario. Puedes obtener la respuesta del servidor en un array asociativo usando `fetch_assoc()` (¿usas PDO o MySQLi?) y a ese resultado le aplicas `json_encode`. Luego, para conformarlo a la respuesta que espera Android le agregas `[` al principio y `]` al final. Y **eso es lo único que debes imprimir, nada más**.

Comment: Haciendo sencillamente esto: `$json=json_encode($set);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo "[".$json."]";` debería imprimirte lo que Android espera, @user1700119

Comment: Puede ser que me esté dando error en Android por los valores null? me muestra la línea entera de campos de un registro en json y me dice

at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Entre los valores tengo null por ejemplo

E/error:: org.json.JSONException: Value {"id":"8783","nombre":"pepe","anterior":null,"usuario":"10","fecha_en_proceso":null,"fecha_terminado":null,"username":"demo"} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

GRACIAS !!!

Comment: El error está en esta línea
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: El resultado del PHP es:
`
[
"{\"id\":\"8783\",\"nombre\":\"pepe\",\"tarifa\":\"\",\"ruta\":\"41\",\"consumo\":null,\"usuario\":\"10\",\"idUsuario\":\"10\",\"username\":\"demo\"}",

  "{\"id\":\"8784\",\"nombre\":\"pepe\",\"tarifa\":\"\",\"ruta\":\"41\",\"consumo\":null,\"usuario\":\"10\",\"idUsuario\":\"10\",\"username\":\"demo\"}",
   false,
"{\"id\":\"8786\",\"nombre\":\"BC_P\",\"tarifa\":\"\",.....}",
......
false,
false,
false,
false,
false,
    
false,
false,
false
]
`

Comment: Para leer el JSONArray en Android debería ser algo así: `JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);` ya que en teoría habría un sólo objeto JSON dentro del Array, no varios objetos. Prueba así, aunque me parece que la respuesta del servidor no es del todo correcta... todos los false que hay fuera de la última `}` no cumplen con el formato de los objetos JSON. Deberías verificar de dónde proceden esos false.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, gracias a todos... no sé porque tengo un problema en el campo "nombre" de la tabla de MySQL, es una tabla que la copie, y como ponía select * from .... me tomaba ese campo y no entiendo porque tiene errores

Les dejo como me quedo armado

Answer (score 0):

Les dejo como me quedo armado

PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$username = $_REQUEST["username"];
if ($con){
    if ($resultado = $con->query("SELECT r.id, r.`lote`, r.`medidor`, r.`tarifa`, u.id AS idUsuario, u.username FROM lecturas r, usuarios u WHERE r.usuario = u.id AND u.username = '$username' AND r.terminado = 0 AND r.enproceso = 0")) {
        if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
            //echo "La selección devolvió filas.\n", $resultado->num_rows;
            $rows = array();
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $row_array = $r;
                array_push($rows,$row_array);
            }
            echo utf8_encode(json_encode($rows));
        }else{
            echo "SQL vacía";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "No nos pudimos conectar con la Base de Datos";
}
?>
```

Y el código android quedo así, como pueden ver envío un parámetro "username" en la url, sé que se puede enviar por el Volley pero así me resulto jajaja

```
button_recibir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
       dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       dialog.setMessage("Recibiendo Trabajos...");
       dialog.show();
       String usuario_z = "demo";
       String URL_2 = "http://www.gesis.com.ar/v2/scripts-E/selectLecturas.php?username=" + usuario_z;

      JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_2,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
       //   ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); // esto lo declare mas arriba
       for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
         try {
              JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
              String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
              String medidor = jsonObject.getString("medidor");
              String lote = jsonObject.getString("lote");
              Log.e("Registro", "ID: " + id + "Medidor: " + medidor);
              al.add(i,"ID: " + id + "Lote: " + lote);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
              dialog.dismiss();
              Log.e("error: ", e.toString());
         }
     }
     dialog.dismiss();
     ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
     fruitsList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
},
 new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override

  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrió un error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.e("ERROR", error.toString());
      dialog.dismiss();
}
}) {

 public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
 HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
 headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
  return headers;
}
};
requestQueue.add(request);
}
});
```